# Is it possible to migrate SharePoint site to new location without disturbing links between pages?

Tags: sharepoint

My team and I need to move our SharePoint site of 47 pages, to a new location. Is there a simple way to move these pages together maintaining their structure?

Also, our pages link to each other a lot via Quick Links, Buttons, Calls to Action, and Hyperlinks. Is it possible to migrate pages without disturbing the integrity of these links? Because each pages contains around 10 links - would be almost 500 for us to update!!

Any help or tips greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could use SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT) to migrate it.
The SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT) is a free and easy to use migration solution to help you migrate content from on-premises SharePoint sites to Microsoft 365.

Migrate your SharePoint Server sites and content to take advantage of the latest collaboration, intelligence, and security solutions in Microsoft 365. The modern experience features in Microsoft SharePoint are designed to be compelling, flexible, and performant.

SPMT supports migration to SharePoint, OneDrive, and Teams from:

SharePoint Server 2010, 2013, and 2016
SharePoint Foundation 2010 and 2013

Below official article for your reference:
[SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool)

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this thread? If you have any concerns, please feel free to reply.